# How do I make my JS switch between different CSS files?

Tags: javascript, css

My Javascript looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const themeStylesheet = document.getElementById('theme');
    const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if(storedTheme){
      themeStylesheet.href = storedTheme;
    }
    const themeToggle = document.getElementById('theme-toggle');
    themeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // if it's light -> go dark
      if(themeStylesheet.href.includes('light')){
        themeStylesheet.href = '../css/dark-theme.css';
        themeToggle.innerText = 'Switch to light mode';
      } else {
        // if it's dark -> go light
        themeStylesheet.href = '../css/light-theme.css';
        themeToggle.innerText = 'Switch to dark mode';
      }
      // save the preference to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('theme',themeStylesheet.href)  
  })
})
```

It should toggle different css files but it cannot find them.
My file tree looks like this:

```
app/
  static/
    myapp/
      css/
        style.css
        light-theme.css
        dark-theme.css
      js/
        main.js
```

Ps. I'm using Django if that makes a difference

Comment: You should tell us more details about your code

Comment: If you assign a relative URL  to  `themeStylesheet.href` then it has to be relative to the URL of the page that is currently shown, not relative to the JavaScript file in which you change the URL.

Comment: Thanks! I copied the relative paths can pasted them in the JS, but it still cannot find them. Any ideas why?

Comment: @s.hesam I'm sorry I'm a bit of a newbie, what code would you like more details of? My css files?